# JSON format in KnockoutJS

Tags: sql, json, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, durandal

I am getting JSON format like below:

```
[
{
    "moduleName": null,
    "bundleKey": "title",
    "bundleValue": "Manage cost code",
    "id": 4,
    "createdBy": 0,
    "modifiedBy": 0,
    "createdDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "modifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "rowVersion": null,
    "isDeleted": false
},
{
    "moduleName": null,
    "bundleKey": "name",
    "bundleValue": "steve",
    "id": 5,
    "createdBy": 0,
    "modifiedBy": 0,
    "createdDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "modifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "rowVersion": null,
    "isDeleted": false
}]
```

I would like to format that as a key-value pair, like the following:

```
[{"title":"Manage cost code", "name":"steve"}]
```

Whether it is possible to format JSON like this.

Or is it possible to get data directly from a database in the format below?

I do not want to query the column name, only its values should be queried.

Comment: Could you please show (and explain) what you have already tried in your attempts to get it working? Also, it does not seem related to knockout or durandal at all, so please remove those tags and change the title of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it clientside, just use a simple reduce function

```
var src = [...];
var result = src.reduce( function(prev, current) {
    prev[current.bundleKey] = current.bundleValue;
    return prev;
}, {} );
```